# Automatically play slideshow of Mac Photos app

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, photos

I'm trying to run slideshow of Photos app on Mac Yosemite automatically.
I believe using Apple Script or Javascript using Script Editor
is one way to achieve it. I can access the target album from the editor
with the code below, but cannot figure out how to play slideshow.

```
tell application "Photos"
    tell container "targetAlbum"
        properties
    end tell
end tell
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Applescript Dictionary says `media item` has to be contained `application`, `albums`, or `moments`. Class `container` is just a generic for `albums`, `folders`, etc.

```
tell application "Photos" to start slideshow using media items of ¬
album "targetAlbum"
```

Comment: thanks for the comment.  
I tried the code above, but it returns error with  

    number -1728 from album "targetAlbum"

saying

    Error occured in Photos. Cannot take album "targetAlbum"

it sounds like specifying the album name is wrong. I tried with album id, but it was same. Do you know what to use there? or does it work in your machine?  

thanks